# What is the point of having variable declarations in function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I stumbled upon a function that looked like this:

```
function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length){
  ...some code
}
```

Is this the same as writing:

```
function pivot(arr){
  let start = 0;
  let end = arr.length;
  ...some code
}
```

If so, are there any particular use cases in which declaring variables in the parameter of a function is advantageous other than for the sake of brevity?

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters is full of many clever examples of why this feature is useful

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing in the function signature is parameters that have a default value. This allows you to pass some or all of the parameters at your discretion, while ensuring there is a usable value for each variable.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing in this case is the [Default Parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20function%20parameters%20default,value%20if%20they%20are%20undefined%20.). Here you can pass any values against these params, say `start` as 5 and `end` as 15. If you don't specify any values, the default values will be considered, i.e start as 0 and end as the length of `arr`

```
function pivot(arr, start = 0, end = arr.length){
  ...some code
}
```

On the other hand What you're seeing below is one variable declared (`start`) and another value (`end`) getting extracted from the parameter `arr`:

```
function pivot(arr){
  let start = 0;
  let end = arr.length;
  ...some code
}
```